# Found a line-word given as a pattern another line-word, awk, perl, sed, grep?

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

Good day.

Sorry for the title of this question, but it's difficult for me explain this.

I have a file with something like this (hundred of servers)

```
mainserver1
--virtualserver1
---- container1
---- container2
--virtualserver2
--virtualserver3
---- container3
---- container4
---- container5
-- virtualserver4
---- container6
---- container7
---- container8
---- container9
---- container10
---- container11
---- container12
---- container13
mainserver2
mainserver3
mainserver4
--virtualserver5
---- container14
---- container15
--virtualserver6
--virtualserver7
mainserver5
mainserver6
```

It means I have:

```
physicals servers
--virtual servers running on the physcal servers
---- containers (zones/dockers) running on virtual servers
```

Names can be different, I'm taking as a guide "--", "----" and physical hosts that start with [a-z].

and as you can notice there is no space between "--virtualserverx" and there is one in "---- continerx"

I want to find for some server and get the parent server.

**Output expected**

```
./find_parent_server.sh container10
mainserver1
--virtualserver4
---- container10

./find_parent_server.sh virtualserver4
mainserver1

./find_parent_server.sh mainserver1
mainserver1 is a Physical server (i think i can manage this)
```

Is it possible to do it?

I was trying with grep and then some with perl, but not working as I expected, but better than nothing.

```
tac allservers | perl -lne 'print if /container10/ .. /^[a-z]/'
---- container10
---- container9
---- container8
---- container7
---- container6
-- virtualserver4
---- container5
---- container4
---- container3
--virtualserver3
--virtualserver2
---- container2
---- container1
--virtualserver1
mainserver1
```

Some light will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What nesting is there (if at all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

Here's a program that answers your question directly

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $wanted = shift or die <<__USAGE__;
Usage:
    $0 <server name>

__USAGE__

my @ancestry;

open my $fh, '<', 'servers.txt' or die $!;

my $found;

while ( <$fh> ) {

  next unless / (-*) \s* (\S+) /x;
  my $index = length($1) / 2;
  $ancestry[$#ancestry = $index] = $2;

  if ( $2 eq $wanted ) {
    if ( @ancestry == 1 ) {
      printf "%s is a Physical server\n", $2;
    }
    else {
      printf "%s %s\n", '--' x $_, $ancestry[$_] for 0 .. $#ancestry;
    }
    ++$found;
    last;
  }
}

printf "Server %s is unknown\n", $wanted unless $found;
```

### output

```
>find_parent_server container10
 mainserver1
-- virtualserver4
---- container10

>find_parent_server virtualserver4
 mainserver1
-- virtualserver4

>find_parent_server mainserver1
mainserver1 is a Physical server

>find_parent_server container16
Server container16 is unknown
```

---

#### Original

Here's a way to build a hash that relates each node to its parent using your own data. It expects the server file as a parameter on the command line. If you need any help to use the resulting hash then please say so

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( @ancestry, %parents );

while ( <> ) {
  next unless / (-*) \s* (\S+) /x;
  my $index = length($1) / 2;
  $ancestry[$#ancestry = $index] = $2;
  $parents{$2} = $index ? $ancestry[-2] : 'NONE';
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%parents
```

#### output

```
{
  container1     => "virtualserver1",
  container10    => "virtualserver4",
  container11    => "virtualserver4",
  container12    => "virtualserver4",
  container13    => "virtualserver4",
  container14    => "virtualserver5",
  container15    => "virtualserver5",
  container2     => "virtualserver1",
  container3     => "virtualserver3",
  container4     => "virtualserver3",
  container5     => "virtualserver3",
  container6     => "virtualserver4",
  container7     => "virtualserver4",
  container8     => "virtualserver4",
  container9     => "virtualserver4",
  mainserver1    => "NONE",
  mainserver2    => "NONE",
  mainserver3    => "NONE",
  mainserver4    => "NONE",
  mainserver5    => "NONE",
  mainserver6    => "NONE",
  virtualserver1 => "mainserver1",
  virtualserver2 => "mainserver1",
  virtualserver3 => "mainserver1",
  virtualserver4 => "mainserver1",
  virtualserver5 => "mainserver4",
  virtualserver6 => "mainserver4",
  virtualserver7 => "mainserver4",
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, it works pretty good, I dont have enogh knowladge in perl to do something like that. I was trying with bash/sh but it is so dificult. Need to learn perl but I heard it is the devil hehe.

Comment: @user1686910: Don't listen to them. It was the Big New Thing twenty years ago, and it's got many times better

Comment: k, got you, I will try it, but maybe will post more and more doubts/question here haha. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`@ARGV` is the arguments given, so, in your case of `./find_parent_server.pl container10`, `container10` is found in `$ARGV[0]`. `shift`ing it off allows the use of the magical `<>`, which reads from STDIN or provided file names.

```
use feature qw{ say } ;
use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $input = shift
    or die("usage\n") ;

my $host = '' ;
my $virt = '' ;
while (<>) {
    chomp ;
    elsif (m{([^-\s]\S*)}) {
        $host = $1;
        next if $host ne $input;

        say $host ;
        }
    elsif (m{^--\s*([^-\s]\S*)}) {
        $virt = $1;
        next if $virt ne $input;

        say $host ;
        say "-- $virt" ;
        }
    elsif (m{^----\s*([^-\s]\S*)}) {
        my $container = $1;
        next if $container ne $input;

        say $host ;
        say "-- $virt" ;
        say "---- $container" ;
        }
    }
```

If your names have spaces in them, replace `[^-\s]\S*` with `[^-\s].*`.

Comment: For uncuddled elses the practice is to let the closing block brace `}` be vertically aligned with the following `elsif`.. see [`Perl-Tidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/docs/tutorial.pod) and [`perlstyle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlstyle)..

Comment: I set my perltidyrc to give me this result. It may not be perlstyle, but there's more than one way to do it.

Comment: @VarLogRant, But not all of them good. This is the worse style I've seen; it's completely different than anyone else's. That makes your code extremely hard to read.

Comment: Not completely different from Ratliff. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Ratliff_style

Answer (score 2):

Could probably do it with a regex -

```
 # (?ms)(?|^($item)()()|^(\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*?^(--\h*$item)()|^(\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*^(--\h*\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*?^(----\h*$item))

 (?ms)
 (?|
      ^ 
      ( $item )                     # (1)
      ( )                           # (2)
      ( )                           # (3)
   |  
      ^ 
      ( \w+ )                       # (1)
      (?:
           (?! ^ \w )
           . 
      )*?
      ^  
      ( -- \h* $item )              # (2)
      ( )                           # (3)
   |  
      ^ 
      ( \w+ )                       # (1)
      (?:
           (?! ^ \w )
           . 
      )*
      ^  
      ( -- \h* \w+ )                # (2)
      (?:
           (?! ^ \w )
           . 
      )*?
      ^  
      ( ---- \h* $item )            # (3)
 )
```

Perl snippet:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $servers = <DATA>;

my @ary = ( 'container10', 'virtualserver4', 'mainserver1');

foreach my $item ( @ary )
{
    if ( $servers =~ /(?ms)(?|^($item)()()|^(\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*?^(--\h*$item)()|^(\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*^(--\h*\w+)(?:(?!^\w).)*?^(----\h*$item))/ )
    {
        print "Found '$item' :\n";
        print "$1\n" if (length($1));
        print "$2\n" if (length($2));
        print "$3\n" if (length($3));
        print "\n";
    }
}


__DATA__

mainserver1
--virtualserver1
---- container1
---- container2
--virtualserver2
--virtualserver3
---- container3
---- container4
---- container5
-- virtualserver4
---- container6
---- container7
---- container8
---- container9
---- container10
---- container11
---- container12
---- container13
mainserver2
mainserver3
mainserver4
--virtualserver5
---- container14
---- container15
--virtualserver6
--virtualserver7
mainserver5
mainserver6
```

Output:

```
Found 'container10' :
mainserver1
-- virtualserver4
---- container10

Found 'virtualserver4' :
mainserver1
-- virtualserver4

Found 'mainserver1' :
mainserver1
```

Comment: Could you explain your regexp to me? I saw such "($item)()()|" before however I did not understand yet how it should work or how to combine these together. Anyway nice solution!

Comment: Are you proposing that as a real solution?

Answer (score 1):

Storing it in hash in tree structure and then printing it according to your needs. Be careful about `--` and `----` i.e you shouldn't put extra spaces there.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ();
my $key1;
my $key2;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    chomp;

    if ( /^[a-z]+/ ) {
        $key1 = $_;
        $hash{$key1} = {};
    }

    if ( /^--[a-z]+/ ) {
        $key2 = $_;
        $key2 =~ s/--//g;
        $hash{$key1}{$key2} = [];
    }

    if ( /^---- [a-z]+/ ) {
        $_ =~ s/---- //g;
        push( @{ $hash{$key1}{$key2} }, $_ );
    }
}

my $server = $ARGV[0];
my $flag   = 0;

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {

    foreach my $nkey ( keys %{ $hash{$key} } ) {

        if ( $server eq $nkey ) {
            $flag = 1;
            print "$key \n--$server \n";
            last;
        }
        elsif ( grep { $server eq $_ } @{ $hash{$key}{$nkey} } ) {
            $flag = 1;
            print "$key \n--$nkey \n---- $server \n";
            last;
        }
    }
}

print "Oops!! No Such server \n" if ( $flag == 0 );

__DATA__
mainserver1
--virtualserver1
---- container1
---- container2
--virtualserver2
--virtualserver3
---- container3
---- container4
---- container5
--virtualserver4
---- container6
---- container7
---- container8
---- container9
---- container10
---- container11
---- container12
---- container13
mainserver2
mainserver3
mainserver4
--virtualserver5
---- container14
---- container15
--virtualserver6
--virtualserver7
mainserver5
mainserver6
```

Use it like

```
perl script.pl container10
```

Output:

```
mainserver1 
--virtualserver4 
---- container10
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with sed. (yes, it is ugly, but works)

```
(read -p "Search term: " servername;tac list_of_servertree.txt |sed -n "/$servername$/,/^[a-z]/p"|tr '\n' ' ';echo)|sed -e 's/\([^\-]\)\ \([a-zA-Z]\)/\1\n\2/1' -e 's/\(^\|\ \)\(--\ \{0,1\}[a-zA-Z]\)/\n\2/1' |sed 's/^\(-\+[^\-]\+\).*/\1/g'|grep -v '^$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @sln's regex solution.

```
T=container10 perl -0777 -ne 
   'print/.*(^\w\S+.)(?:.*^(--\w\S+.).*?^(---- )|.*?^(--))($ENV{T}\b.)/ms' server.list
```

Capture groups correspond to the input you want. Greedy `.*` expressions take up all the input you don't want, with a non-greedy `.*?` just before your target expression.